# Anonymous user permission issue in SharePoint Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 x64 and Windows Server 2008 x64. I have setup a site with template publishing portal. I have grant anonymous access to all the site.

My question is, if I create a new page, how to grant permission to anonymous user to access (read permission) the page? I got this confusion because, for the permission setting of a page, a permission is set according to a user name (e.g. read permission for user "foo" of a page). Since anonymous user does not have a related "user name", how could I grant read permission to anonymous user?

BTW: I use Windows Forms authentication and Windows NTLM authentication for my sites.

Thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous access relies on the anonymous user account on the Web server. This account is created and maintained by Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS), not your SharePoint site. By default in IIS, the anonymous user account is IUSR_*ComputerName*.

Mikhail